# How to do a many-to-many query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to understand how to use GORM to make query on items with many2many relations but I'm really lost.

I've got the following database model:

```
type Asset struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id             uint            `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    MachineUID     string          `gorm:"type:varchar(128)" json:"machine_uid"`
    AssetToken     string          `gorm:"uniqueIndex;type:varchar(128)"`
    CommandQueries []*CommandQuery `gorm:"many2many:command_asset;"`
}


type CommandQuery struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id      uint     `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    UUID    string   `gorm:"type:varchar(128)" json:"uuid"`
    CmdType int      `json:"cmdtype"`
    CmdArgs string   `gorm:"type:varchar(128)" json:"cmdargs"`
    Assets  *[]Asset `gorm:"many2many:command_asset;"`
    Active  bool
}
```

First, i'm successfully trying to retrieve an asset from a token with something like this:

```
token := "test-token"
var result Asset
db.Where("asset_token = ?", token).First(&result)

if result.Id == 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("Asset cannot be found in database")
}
```

But fom this returned struct, i would like to retrive all CommandQuery objects where:

- this asset is in CommandQuery.assets
- Where CommandQuery.active = true

I tried many things but nothing works, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to load a slice of `CommandQuery` objects, and these objects should contain only assets where `asset_token` should be equal to the token you passed. Also, return only `CommanQuery` objects that have `active=true`.

If this is the case, it can be done like this:

```
token := "test-token"
var list []CommandQuery{}
tx := db.Preload("Assets", func (gdb *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB{
           return gdb.Where("asset_token = ?", token)
         }).
         Where("active = ?", true).Find(&list)

if tx.Error == nil {
    return nil, tx.Error
}

return *list, nil
```

In short, [custom preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL) is used to load assets into command query objects.

Comment: thank you very much, it was what i wanted to do. Just another thing: from the CommandQuery slice, is it possible to avoid returning the "assets" field directly from gorm query?

Comment: what do you mean by "avoid returning the assets"?

Comment: When i return the CommandQuery slice, i don't necessary want an user to see all others for which this query was created. I can manually clear the "assets" field of each structure but i wonder if it's possible to choose not to map this field to this specific query

Comment: If you leave out the `Preload` function from this query, none of the assets will be populated.